# How to get the autocomplete feature for a taxonomy term profile field visible on the registration form?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, users, ajax

I have Profile2 and Profile2 Registration Path modules enabled, I set up two different profiles, and for one of them I created a field which is a taxonomy term with the Autocomplete term widget (tagging).

When adding a user within the administration interface, I have the autocomplete widget working, but for anonymous users trying to create a profile the widget is not even attached to the field... I know it is not attached because a field with the widget has a "autocomplete" class and an icon for ajax status in background, but the field on the registration form has no class..

How to add this widget ? Is it a permission issue ? or adding the class to the field through `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` could be enough ? (I don't have the field in the `$form` array though...

Comment: Turns out it is a permission issue : adding the permission for anonymous users to `View published content` solves my problem as I do not have any reason to not let them see the website content.. 

I guess for websites where content is for registered users only, this permission would not be granted and the widget would not be used on the taxonomy term field.. Maybe the `Content Access` module could help those use-cases

Comment: In the future, instead of leaving a comment, you should answer your own question and then mark that answer as accepted.  *Drupal Answers* encourages you to answer your own questions when you find the answer; this helps future users who may have the same question that you did.

Comment: I couldn't answer my own question yesterday, I had to wait 8hours before I could do, so instead of leaving people in the doubt, I did answer my own question by leaving a comment :)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it is a permission issue : adding the permission for anonymous users to `View published content` solves my problem as I do not have any reason to not let them see the website content

I guess for websites where content is for registered users only, this permission would not be granted and the widget would not be used on the taxonomy term field.. Maybe the `Content Access` module could help those use-cases